# Chrome Downloads Virus Scan Failed

Tags: google-chrome, download, anti-virus

Chrome just recently updated (Version 24.0.1312.57) and I can't download files no more. I think the latter is the result of the former.

Internet Explorer (8) has no problems.

OS: Windows XP SP 3.

Every time I try I get 'Virus Scan Failed' next to the file name in the Download box at the bottom of the screen.

When I look at my Downloads (chrome://downloads/) it says 'Download Failed' but if I try and do a new download it says 'Anti-virus software failed unexpectedly while scanning this file.'

I've looked the ['Common Download Errors' page](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2898334), especially the advice concerning 'Possible causes of error message: Virus Scan Failed'. Not much help here. I have Symantec Endpoint antivirus installed, its a corporate install and I can't change any of the settings so I can't attack it from that angle.

I can't find anything related to the Microsoft Attachment Manager in my registry either.

I found one thread recommending running [Microsoft Fix It to reset Internet Explorer settings](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737), as this would fix this problem in Chrome. It didn't

So, any advice?

Comment: Have you tried to delete your Chrome profile.  Do you even have anti-virus software installed?  IE8 doens't have any protection like Chrome 24 does on downloads so its not a good test case to see if something is working.

Comment: Do I want to delete my Chrome profile? As mentioned, anti-virus is Symantec Endpoint.

Comment: You will have to go to to your IT department to determine if this is a system configuration problem. I missed the statement about the anti-virus.  A Microsoft Fixit wouldn't be able to resolve a conflict with `Chrome` and `Symantec Endpoint`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this was a bug in Version 24.0.1312.5 of Chrome

WHen the latest version of Chrome installed itself (Version 25.0.1364.97 m) I was once more able to download pdf/zip/doc/etc files without a problem.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the following registry key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE >SOFTWARE >Microsoft >Windows >CurrentVersion >Policies >Attachments`

Double click on “`ScanWithAntivirus`” registry key and change its value to “`1`” which is by default “`3`“.

Changing the key value to “1”

See: [How To Fix Google Chrome Download "Virus Scan Failed" Error](https://www.itechfever.com/fix-google-chrome-virus-scan-failed-error/).

Answer (score 2):

Create a new registry file, such as `ScanWithAntiVirus-1.reg` with the following content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Attachments]
"ScanWithAntiVirus"=dword:00000001
```

The file can be created with any editor such as Notepad, just copy and paste.

When finish, save it (make sure it got `.reg` extension at the end), and run it by double clicking on it. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I was plagued w/ this same download problem in Chrome, but also in IE and FireFox too.  Tried everything.  Nothing worked until I did a thorough AVG2013 uninstall including AVG in my Start Menu, registry keys, Program Files AVG directory folder removal, etc.  And voila, the downloads keep on coming!

Thinking back, this whole Win7 DL problem started when upgraded to the new AVG2013 engine.  I've decided to go w/ Avast! free version for my anti-virus protection.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error when downloading (running XP Pro 32bit SP3). Antivirus is Symantec Endpoint and i couldn't find any problems in here.

Go to the settings tab in Chrome, the 'show advanced settings. and tick the 'ask where to save each file before downloading'.

When i have this ticked the files will download, when it is unticked i get the same error again... So could well work for you too.

Strange!

Answer (score -2):

My Fix as of 09/09/14...

Go to this site: http://www.itechfever.com/fix-google-chrome-virus-scan-failed-error/

Scroll almost half way down to "Another Method to Fix Virus Scan Failed Error."

Use another computer, I used my Chrome book, to DL the very small "Virus Scan Fix" file to a USB drive.

Copy to the troublesome PC, extract the .rar file and run "Virus scan fix.reg"

Reboot.

End of problem

Comment: I don't like this fix as it disables scanning across all browsers permanently. Also, this was already provided as an answer...

Comment: A .reg file is a text file and you shouldn't go to through so many steps on other sites for a simple registry entry